# Proof about cyclic module

Tags: linear-algebra

I have to proof the following:
Let A be a commutative ring, be M a cyclic A-module and $\varphi : M\rightarrow M$
a A-linear function. Then there exists an $a \in A $ with $\varphi (x)=ax$ for all $x\in M$.

But I feel kinda lost with what to do, would really appreciate any help as I can't find much information about this.

Comment: I know you put up the bounty after I gave my answer, but nobody provided another one.  Can you tell me what you find unsatisfactory about it?

Answer (score 3):

By the definition of cyclic, we have an $m\in M$ such that every element of $M$ is of the form $am$ for some $a\in A$ (N.B., if your definition of cyclic isn't that there is a single generator, but rather that $M=A/I$, then let $m$ be the image of $1$ in the quotient).  In particular, $\phi(m)=am$ for some $a\in A$.  We wish to show that $\phi(x)=ax$ for all $x\in m$.

Given $x\in M$, write $x=bm$ for some $b\in A$.  Then $$\phi(x)=\phi(bm)=b\phi(m)=b(am)=(ba)m=(ab)m=a(bm)=ax.$$

It is worth noting where we used commutivity here.

Answer (score 2):

Take a generator $m$ of $M$, that is $M=Rm$. Any nonzero element is a generator, as $M$ is cyclic. Now $\varphi(m)\in M=Rm$, so $\varphi(m)=am$
for some $a\in R$. Can you prove that $\varphi(x)=ax$ for **all** $x\in M$?

Comment: So because M is cyclic, every x∈M is a generator which means φ(x)∈M and because φ is a A-linear function there has to exist an a∈A so that φ(x)=ax for all x∈M? I still don't really understand it...

Comment: Could you please explain it a bit more?

Comment: It is not true that any nonzero element is a generator.  Consider $A=\mathbb Z$, $M=A/(4)$.  Then the image of $2$ in the quotient is a nonzero non-generator.